# Edit Style (Color/Font ect.) of Bootstrap with CSS or better use less

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

Looks like its not that easy to edit the style of a Bootstrap site via CSS, althoug i used style.css but my changes never show up (yes ist loaded after bootstrap.css)
I heard about LESS, is it the only (or just the better way) to edit a bootstrap style?

I need to be able to edit and have live changes, i need to be able to change font style of h1, size and color of navbar, color of buttons...everything.

I found a site describing the process, is that correct ?
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/594098/How-to-customize-Twitter-Bootstrap-to-fit-your-web

Or is there a better way to edit the lass, do i realy need a local server ?
I used layoutit.com for the layout and Brackets for styling and html work.

By the way, is there anything like layoutit.com for the Foundation frontend other then Divshot (dont like that and its not free)

Comment: Use something like Firebug to see which rules override yours, and then use a selector with higher priority, or use `!important` as a last resource.

Comment: The site you've linked to (codeproject) is the best way to customize Bootstrap (in my opinion).  But, it is confusing at first.  With that tutorial you will need an understanding of LESS.  They download the files from Github, not from the Bootstrap website, which gives them all the Bootstrap files split out, rather than minified versions.  If you just want to use CSS, and don't mind overriding a number of styles, you could just download direct from Bootstrap site, then link your stylesheet below the bootstrap.min.css.  You can use the same selectors as them as your stylesheet will be after.

Answer (score 0):

> Looks like its not that easy to edit the style of a Bootstrap site via
>   CSS, although i used style.css but my changes never show up

Use something like Firebug to see which rules override yours, and then use a selector with higher priority, or use `!important` as a last resource

> I heard about LESS, is it the only (or just the better way) to edit a
>   bootstrap style?

I have never used LESS, but it is a CSS precompiler.

Then, LESS code is converted into CSS. So LESS won't solve your problem, because you can code CSS directly.

> do i really need a local server?

Only if your site runs in a local server, AFAIK

Comment: I mean, do i need to run my website in a local server to see the changes i made with less ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to mess with original bootstrap files. Instead, create your own css file and add only those classes you want to change. For example:

```
.body {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

In this way you can edit it really easy and quick, you don't mess with less files or bootstrap files and if you are not satisfied you can easily go back to the originals!